# Qt project file and system environment variable

Tags: qt, environment-variables, qmake

I work on `Mac Os X` with `Qt Creator` and I want to use a `system environment variable` as a path in my `.pro` file. The variable is set in the `Project => Build Environment` and here's a part of my `pro` file :

```
DEPENDPATH += . \
        $$VLC_QT_PATH
INCLUDEPATH += . \
        $$VLC_QT_PATH
```

and some output from the terminal :

```
Mac:~ me$ echo $VLC_QT_PATH
/Users/me/vlc/include
Mac:~ me$ cd $VLC_QT_PATH
Mac:~ me$ find . -iname "vlc.h"
./vlc/vlc.h
```

But the include `#include "vlc/vlc.h"` isn't working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#variables):

> To obtain the contents of an environment value when qmake is run, use the $$(...) operator

So it should be `$$(VLC_QT_PATH)`